# How to access the value of inline map through the value of an enum in SpEL?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflow, spring-el

I have created a Thymeleaf fragment which I include in all **view-states** views of my flow.

```
<th:block th:fragment="flow-messages" 
     th:with="alertTypes = ${ {'INFO':'alert-info','ERROR':'alert-error','WARNING':'alert-warning'} }">
    <div 
       class="alert"
       th:each="message: ${flowRequestContext.messageContext.allMessages}" 
       th:classappend="${alertTypes.get(message.severity)}">
       <p th:text="${message.text}">Message text</p>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

As you can see above, I initialize a map with severity levels (org.springframework.binding.message.Severity) and the associated bootstrap class.

The problem is that **alertTypes.get (message.severity)** does not work (returns an empty value). And I have no way to add the corresponding class.

Anyone know how I can fix this?.

Comment: is alertTypes an enum on your project? can you post the code?

Comment: alertTypes is defined on th:with.  th:with="alertTypes = ${ {'INFO':'alert-info','ERROR':'alert-error','WARNING':'alert-warning'} }"

Comment: @SergioSánchezSánchez did you verify the value of message.severity is right? I checked the map is working correctly, btw is alert-danger not error

Comment: Try to hardcode to verify your map is working th:classappend="${alertTypes.get('INFO')}"

Comment: I created the messages this way messageContext.addMessage(builder.error().code("frontend.checkout.create.address.failed").build()); Then the message.severity will be equal to ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `th:classappend="${alertTypes.get(message.severity.toString())}"` instead of `th:classappend="${alertTypes.get(message.severity)}"`.

The inline map you created has Strings for its keys (and not Enums of type Severity) -- so calling get() with an Enum value won't match.

Comment: this work fine, but I have also had to remove the single quotes 'INFO' -> INFO